# Running a software on your machine without any download/install. How it works

Tags: installation, windows-installer

Googling didn't help a lot. May be I am not using the right keywords. I am having a little hard time how to describe the question, so let me describe the scenario and hopefully someone can point me to the right direction.

With a traditional installer, you download a program that get installed on your computer and then you can run it. In some cases, software probably doesn't get installed but it still gets downloaded and run on your computer. However, some software market themselves as `No installation and easy to use`. They somehow make their software run on your machine from the cloud, I guess. I wonder what could be the technology involve here and how they can run a software on your machine without installing it? May be this methodology could be applicable for very specific use-cases and not for all type of software?

Comment: Not really on-topic for ServerFault. Part of *"No installation and easy to use"* is marketing speak and the technical part is more software design/engineering. But you can have a single self-contained binary without external dependencies or an interpreted program that runs without unpacking/installing it on your system, directly from the download location.  Alternatively you have "software" that runs mostly in your web browser or uses a commonly installed framework. See for example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: It could simply refer to "SaaS" / "cloud" based software, i.e. an application that is run entirely in your browser by accessing the provider's site. Then it leverages the technologies of the web (HTML, CSS, Javascript) and half a ton of libraries and frameworks that run on top of that. It could actually not run anything on your computer, just display stuff, with all the code running server-side, or it could run JS code in your browser. Alternatives used to include Java and Flash but those are on their way out (or are already out)